# how to create a Storm table with no primary key?

Tags: python, mysql, database, orm, storm-orm

I'm trying to use Storm to create an ORM to an existing MySQL db.  I'm trying to create a table Class for one of the tables but I'm getting this error:

`storm.exceptions.ClassInfoError: <class 'statsstorm.Aggframe'> has no primary key information`

This table has no primary key, or any combination of columns that produce a unique row.  It functions more like a log.

How do I create a Storm table class with no primary key?

```
class Aggframe(Storm):
    """ Storm-based interface to the stats.aggframe table."""

    __storm_table__ = 'aggframe'

    user = Unicode()
    dept = Unicode()
    frame_avg = Float()
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a table without a primary key?  Why did you skip those classes in your DBMS theory course?

Comment: The table wasn't created by me, and I probably won't be able to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a compound key:

https://storm.canonical.com/Manual#Defining_compound_keys

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend that you create a table without a PK.

If anything, add an IDENTITY column in that table and use as PK.

Comment: I would agree, but unfortunately, the table was created long ago and I likely won't be able to change it.